# Noise margin of a cascade connection of Schottky clamped transistor and a regular transistor

Tags: transistors, schottky

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzazpR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a buffer.

So what's the \$Vil - Vol\$ ? I would have thought it's it's \$Vbe - Vces\$, but that's incorrect. Does Q1 ever go in saturation? Advice on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

That is a Baker Clamp. That transistor does not go into hard saturation, thus very fast astable (2 transistor) R+C oscillators are possible. My first design leader used that in simple but fast ADC clock generators.

Answer (score 0):

\$V{ih}=V_{be}+I_b*R_b\$

\$ V_{il}\$ is pulled to ground.